# How can I use an already configured integration runtime (IR) with an Azure data factory that is recreated?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

One of the data factories that we are running got deleted. The VM running the IR (integration runtime) is still working - and as soon as the data factory was recreated it connected to this:

[Self hosted IR connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGzQC.png)

But what are the steps I need to take in order to get this working from the Azure side?

[Azure portal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8OVw.png)

Regards,
Andy

- recreated the data factory

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question here. I have done this using the following solution:

1. Log into the VM
2. Remove the existing IR
3. Launch the Azure Portal from the VM
4. Select the relevant ADF
5. Delete any (not linked/shared) IRs that this ADF has defined
6. Create a new IR, and use the express setup on this computer
7. Wait for it to install and configure.

Voila!

Regards,
Andy